# UpdateInputAccessTimeHook in Hive doesn't implement Hook interface so is it not usable from Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I ran `set hive.exec.pre.hooks=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook;`  which results in below Error:

> FAILED: Hive Internal Error:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook
>   cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.Hook)

on any queries. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/hooks/UpdateInputAccessTimeHook.java) of that class, which doesn't implement Hook interface as stated in the error. But all other class in the [same package](https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/hooks) implements Hook interface. So am I using this class in the wrong way or it is a bug? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set it in `hive-site.xml` as:

```xml
<property>
    <name>hive.exec.pre.hooks</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec</value>
</property>
```

or in hive session as set

```
hive.exec.pre.hooks=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.UpdateInputAccessTimeHook$PreExec;
```

It works for me in Hive 2.1